# On Azure DevOps Server 2019, how can I merge the master branch into develop branch WITHOUT its policies being applied?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

On a NuGet library, I'm using the `develop` branch as the continuous integration branch. I've set policies on it so that no pull request can be approved without it being built. Furthermore, any successful merge will cause a CI build to run and eventually a prerelease NuGet package will be created and pushed within a private NuGet feed.

When I'm satisfied with the prerelease behavior, I create an additional PR to merge `develop` into `master`, which in turn causes a CD build to be started, that will lead to a production release of the NuGet package.

Here's the thing though: it may happen that I'll want to create a hotfix branch straight from master, make some changes and then make a new PR of that branch straight back to master. This will launch the usual CD pipelines and cause a new release in production (with an incremented patch number).

The thing is though that I'll want to merge master back into develop thereafter, which right now creates a new prerelease version (which is irrelevant at this point).

Do I have a way to tell Azure DevOps that in the special case of master being merged back into develop, branch policies should be skipped? Do I even *have* to make a PR from master to develop, when really all I want to do is merging a previously approved PR from hotfix to master!?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: To the person who voted this to be too broad, do you have any advice on how to make the question any more specific than "how to skip branch policies when merging branches on the server"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I merge the master branch into develop branch WITHOUT its policies being applied?

As we know, branch policies is used to protect the target branch. Once we have set up the branch policies on the target branch and enable it, any changes submitted to the target branch will trigger the branch policies.

So, there is no such out of box way to merge the master branch into develop branch WITHOUT its policies being applied. **As workaround**, we could set the option `Bypass policies when completing pull requests` to `Allow`, Branches->develop->Branch Security:

[image]

With this settings, this specify user could merge the master branch into develop branch WITHOUT its policies being applied.

> Do I have a way to tell Azure DevOps that in the special case of
>   master being merged back into develop, branch policies should be
>   skipped?

Just like I answered above, we could not bypass the branch policies for the special case, because we could not defined the bypass rule for each special case. But we could provided the bypass rule for some specify users.

> Do I even have to make a PR from master to develop, when really all I
>   want to do is merging a previously approved PR from hotfix to master!?

The short answer is no.

Let me give a sketch:

[image]

On your case, when you have a `hotfix` branch based on the `master` branch. After we complete the development task on the `hotfix` branch, we will merge `hotfix` to the `master` branch. Before we complete the PR, we need to pass the branch policies we set on the `master` branch.

Then we need to marge back `master` branch into `develop`. You want to bypass the branch policies on the `develop`, because we have already PR the `hotfix` commit when we marge to the master branch, am I right?

If yes, this depends on whether the branch policies on the `master` and `develop` branches are the same (or higher) to determine whether you need to make a PR from master to develop.

As mentioned above, **branch policies is used to protect the target branch**. If branch policies on the `master` and `develop` branches are the same, we could bypass the branch policies on the `develop` branches. However, if branch policies on the `master` and `develop` branches are different, we still need make a PR from master to develop to protect the `develop` branch, even though we have already completed the merge of the hotfix to the master branch.

**In summary**, when we set `master` branch as the main branch and the `master` branch set the branch policies of the highest specification, we could merge `master` to `develop` branch **without** PR, when really all I want to do is merging a previously approved PR from hotfix to master!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured as much. I was just hoping that there would be a more streamlined process for this. I'm having a hard time believing that bigger players in the industry who chose to trust Azure DevOps as their CI/CD engine actually are okay with the way it operates. I was hoping I was doing something wrong and that there would be a far better way to do things, but alas it seems that's how it is.